# Properties of weakly convergent sequence in Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Assume you have a sequence $x_n$ of functions in a seperable Hilbert space, where $\|x_n\|$ converges to some real number $r$. On top assume $x_n$ is weakly convergent to some $x$. Is $r=\|x\|$?

My attempt: $\|x\|^2 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty |\langle x, e_i\rangle|^2 = \lim \limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty |\langle x_n, e_i\rangle|^2 = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\| x_n\|^2 = r^2$

Yet I don't know why I can pull the limit in the series.

Comment: Are you aware of Weierstrass M-test?

Comment: How would that help out here?

Comment: I thought for a moment that you can use it show uniform convergence which would give the ability to interchange limits. However, as daw wrote and showed, this is not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, this is not true. In general, you only have $\|x\| \le \liminf \|x_n\|=r$. A counterexample to equality is the sequence $(e_i)$ itself, it converges weakly to zero.

You cannot exchange weak limit and summation. In order to do that, you would need that $\langle e_i, x_n -x \rangle\to 0$ uniformly in $i$.